# UIWebview didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm using webview to load a web site. and I managed to run the apps. 
But my problem Is that I can't load the web site if I pass a wrong password, it only show a white screen.

If I pass the correct username/password, it will load the web site. 
is there a way to handle my authenticate username/password is correct or wrong?

I'm using this code.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM])
{
    NSURLCredential *credentail = [NSURLCredential
                                   credentialWithUser:@"username" 
                                   password:@"Password"
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}}
```

The correct username and password are included in the code above. If I change the username into "user" or password into "pass", I can't load the web site. How can I catch the authentication error?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just found it. just need to add 1 more validation. [[challenge previousFailureCount] == 0. here is the code.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
//receive a authenticate and challenge with the user credential
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM] &&
    [challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
{
    NSURLCredential *credentail = [NSURLCredential 
                                   credentialWithUser:@"username" 
                                   password:@"password"
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
else 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Message" message:@"Invalid credentails" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}
```

thanks. :)

Comment: I have the same issue, but this function never is called :'( I don´t understand why! I already added the `this.webview.delegate = XYZ`. :/